# How to show recursive list from coming api in .net core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have function like this and this function get all subfolders. My Folder Model:

```
public partial class Folder
{
    public Folder()
    {
        Files = new HashSet<File>();
        InverseParentFolder = new HashSet<Folder>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public Guid FileGuid { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int? ParentFolderId { get; set; }
    public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AppUserId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.Folders))]
    public virtual User AppUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentFolderId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Folder.InverseParentFolder))]
    public virtual Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(File.Folder))]
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Folder.ParentFolder))]
    public virtual ICollection<Folder> InverseParentFolder { get; set; }
}
```

And my function :

```
public async Task<List<Folder>> GetAllSubFolders(int folderId)
    {
        List<Folder> result = new List<Folder>();
        await GetFolders(folderId, result);

        return result;
    }


    //Recursive function that take all subfolders inside of one folder.
    private async Task GetFolders(int folderId, ICollection<Folder> result)
    {
        using var context = new FilemanagementContext();

        var folders =await context.Folders.Where(I => I.ParentFolderId== folderId && I.IsDeleted==false).ToListAsync();


        if (folders.Count >0)
        {
            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                if (folder.InverseParentFolder==null)
                    folder.InverseParentFolder = new List<Folder>();

                await GetFolders(folder.Id, folder.InverseParentFolder);

                if (!result.Contains(folder))
                {
                    result.Add(folder);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Simple response message :

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "folderName": "Child Edited Name",
    "fileGuid": "d056e29b-2034-4ecc-a12e-e79d5d2ce494",
    "size": 148,
    "parentFolderId": 2,
    "appUserId": 2,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "createdAt": "2021-03-02T11:22:52.653",
    "appUser": null,
    "parentFolder": null,
    "files": [],
    "inverseParentFolder": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "folderName": "Child Folder 3",
            "fileGuid": "3d559aa8-0216-4498-9de2-896d51110773",
            "size": 0,
            "parentFolderId": 3,
            "appUserId": 2,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "createdAt": "2021-03-03T13:17:27.523",
            "appUser": null,
            "parentFolder": null,
            "files": [],
            "inverseParentFolder": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I will zip this parent and child folders from coming information above. I can already zip some folders and files also i will zip folders on controller.

So my question is how do I zip the folders coming from this recursive function one by one?

Comment: "Coming one by one" assumes IEnumerable, yet you use List.

Comment: I don't see how you can't zip one, if you can zip many.

Comment: I have wwwroot folder like this  [link](https://hizliresim.com/gM5DbD) they're not nested physically but in database they're nested. My problem is not zipping i can do that but I can't do zipping in nested folders like that. Because I don't know how to go all subfolders coming from result [link](https://hizliresim.com/tF6LVn)